# How to Play sound file till it finished in Qt?

Tags: qt

I am using `QSound` to play audio file. Audio file duration is 10 sec.
I have some task after playing the complete 10 sec audio file. So for this I am using `QSound::isFinished` method, but this always returns false instantly. example

Comment: Can we see some example code? I'm curious as to when you are checking QSound::isFinished, and it's not obvious from your question

Answer (score 3):

Based on the current wording of the question, I'm assuming you're checking isFinished immediately, which will indeed return false.

I think you're best bet is to use QTimer and connect it's timeout signal to some slot which will check isFinished. You would start the timer when the sound starts playing. When isFinished returns true, you can stop the timer and do whatever it is that needs doing. If it returns false, wait for the next timeout.

```
// In the .h
// ...

private slots:
    void onTimeout();

private:
    QTimer* timer;
    QSound sound;

// ...


// In the .cpp
// In your constructor
// ...

timer = new Timer();
connect( timer, SIGNAL( timeout() ), this, SIGNAL( onTimeout() ) ),

// ...
// Starting the sound
// ...

sound.play();
timer.start( 10 );  // In milliseconds.


// ...
// onTimeout slot

void MyClass::onTimeout()
{
    if( sound.isFinished() )
    {
        timer.stop();

        // Do some things.
    }
}
```

I chose 10 milliseconds in the assumption that the audio file's of different length could be played. QSound is also not guaranteed to start playback immediately.

If you know **for a fact** that the audio played will always have the same length, you could forgo the isFinished check and change the Timer to a single shot with a duration the same length of the file (plus a bit to account for variable start times). This will result in it only timing out once, and *should* do so after the file has finished. That's not my preferred method, but it is a possibility.

Comment: Thanks i will implement it. but the problem is that isFinished() not returns true ??? then what to do?? when sound starts immediately isFinished() returns false.

Comment: isFinished won't return true until the file has played completely, in your case, roughly 10 seconds after you call play(). Until those 10 seconds have passed (the playback completes) it will return false.

Comment: /* my code is like this 
QSound *player = 0;
player = new QSound("/filepath.wav");
player->play();
while(!player->isFinished);
qDebug() << "soundtrack finished";


So i want to call degug only when sound file finished but when sound starts immediately qDebug starts??

Comment: Comments aren't a great place to put code. I suggest you edit your original question and add the code there.

Comment: I am new to stack overflow..... when i write code it'shows error like
your post contains code please formatted well

Comment: I want to play one sound file . which is 10 sec duration.
I want to do sometask after fully finishing the audio file i.e. after playing sound file 10 sec i have some task to do. my code as follow:
 void MainWindow::on_pushButton()
{
`QSound *player = 0;`
`player = new QSound(C:/user/Desktop/audio.wav);`
`player->play();`
'while(!player.isFinished()); // wait till sound file finished
 'qDebug() << "soundtrack is finished"; 

}

qDebug should call after finishing the sound file. but it called immediately when sound starts

Comment: It's not a good idea to use a while loop like that as it will block your GUI thread. Also, it looks like you have a ; after your while(), which I'm sure is not what you want.

Comment: When you're editing your question, be sure not to use tab characters for code. Use 4 spaces at the beginning of a line to mark is as code, and then use spaces instead of tab characters to indent.

Comment: have you understood my problem what i am trying to do?

Comment: Yes, and I think the solution I suggested in my answer is going to get you where you need to be. Again, I don't advise using a while like that as it will block your thread until the sound file is done, preventing anything else from happening.

Comment: @VivekVishwakarma Glad to hear it. You should accept the answer so others know you've got your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use a QSoundEffect instead and connect to the playingChanged signal.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsoundeffect.html#playing-prop